# How to set json data into chrome storage api and get?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to set json data into chrome storage from fetch url. In my code i need to access name "Grapes". I try to access json and alert directly from fetch data. it works. but after i set into chrome storage and tried to get. it failed. i think the problem is how to set and get json data from chrome storage.

fruits.json

```
{
  "fruits": [
     {"name": "Orange", "color": "Yelow"},
     {"name": "Grapes", "color": "Purple"}
  ]
}
```

Scripts

```
fetch('http://localhost/fruits.json')
 .then(response => {

  return response.json();

 })
 .then(data => {

  chrome.storage.local.set({'fruits': data.fruits});

 });

chrome.storage.local.get('fruits', function (informations) {

alert(informations[1].name.fruits);

});
```

Comment: what is the `error` shown in console

Comment: Use devtools for debugging properly: set a breakpoint inside the callback and inspect `informations` - you'll see it's an object, not an array. You'll see the correct data path is `informations.fruits`.

Answer (score -1):

why are you restricting yourself,  to just chrome? you can use LocalStorage of HTML5 itself.

[LocalStorage W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

You can use getItem and setItem functions to perform the operations

Comment: LocalStorage can't pass value into background and content scripts. It restricted into current domain.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `alert` to output the data, you are using a property that does not exist.

Try using `alert(informations[1].name);` instead of `alert(informations[1].name.fruits);`

The name property should exist and you should see "Grapes" being displayed.